# Is it proper to archive/unarchive NSWindowController?

Tags: objective-c, xcode4, interface-builder, nswindow, nswindowcontroller

I'm having a difficult time understanding what's going wrong. I have an NSWindowController with a NSWindow and a NSTextView.  I want to archive that NSWindowController **and** NSWindow (along with all of its controls) to a file.

Then, I want to unarchive that same NSWindowController and the NSWindow and all views from the file.  But Apple docs say:

`Note: Although the NSWindow class inherits the NSCoding protocol from NSResponder, the class does not support coding. Legacy support for archivers exists but its use is deprecated and may not work. Any attempt to archive or unarchive an NSWindow object using a keyed coding object raises an NSInvalidArgumentException exception.`

Importantly, if I encodeWithObject:windowController, this doesn't store the NSWindow.  Therefore, when I do decodeWithObject for the windowController, the NSWindow isn't loaded.

How do I archive/unarchive the NSWindowController / NSWindow and all of its controls?  What am I missing?

Comment: This is not normal. For what purpose are you archiving the controller and view portions of your app? It's likely there's a far better approach to achieve your goal.

Comment: Basically I'm implementing a Save Document situation.  I want to save the windowcontroller because it contains the internal states of the controller.  and I'm trying to save the nswindow because it has its own internal states of textfields, customviews etc.  I get that I'm doing something wrong, just can't seem to figure out what / how to go about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your answers, this is *absolutely* the *wrong* way to go about this. The only place an archived controller/view object graph makes sense is when it's archived as a nib/xib. A document contains *data*, not bits of the application's machinery.

If you're targeting anything below Lion, save your state somewhere in your document data when the document is saved and restore it when the document is loaded (see the various loading stages [Document-Based Applications Overview](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Documents/Tasks/ImplementingDocApp.html) for an understanding of where/when to do this).

If you're targeting Lion and above, the documentation isn't very detailed yet (and in some cases is completely nonexistent), but Lion supports EXACTLY this with very little effort on your part. See [the WWDC 2011 videos](http://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/), session 119 - Resume and Automatic Termination.

Comment: Hmm.  Not really looking for the resume part - maybe later.  Right now I'm just trying to implement the save part.  Does this mean I should (upon Open Document) create the NSWindowController with a new window, and then run readFromCoder to load the data into the windowcontroller?  Not sure if that makes sense.

Comment: Err ... what good is saving the settings if you're not going to restore it later? Don't get caught up by the name in Lion. Re-read my response.

Comment: I must be entirely missing something.  I'm just trying to save my project to file.  Project being a single NSWindowController and its variables.  I then want to restore it when doing Open Document (misnomer, it's not a NSDocument).

Comment: You may very well be missing the Model-View-Controller concept. Your data is the model. The rest is your application's machinery. You don't save controllers and views, just data.

Comment: Hmm.  Should the controller save the data?  For example, by implementing writeToCoder: where it writes all of the data that it's holding.

Comment: It seems you're missing some basic Cocoa essentials. I suggest spending some time with the docs: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/navigation/#section=Resource%20Types&topic=Getting%20Started In the meantime, here's an article that addresses (in a very general way) how you can save data with Cocoa: http://cocoadevcentral.com/articles/000084.php